# Retrieve data from nested json in js

Tags: javascript, json

I have the `json` response from google elevation service as:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 1340.76708984375,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 27.717098,
            "lng" : 85.346625
         },
         "resolution" : 152.7032318115234
      },
      {
         "elevation" : 1336.588745117188,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 27.712471009522,
            "lng" : 85.34499693093947
         },
         "resolution" : 152.7032318115234
      },
      {
         "elevation" : 1331.822631835938,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 27.707844,
            "lng" : 85.343369
         },
         "resolution" : 152.7032318115234
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

I am able to retrieve elevation and resolution using (here lets take value of first array 0)

```
results[0].elevation
```

but I am not being able to retrieve lat and lng value using

```
results[0].location.lat
```

which I think is correct approach.

Can anyone tell me where I am wrong and how can I retrieve data of lat and lng.

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log` `results[0].location` and `results[0].location.lat`?

Comment: [Nothing wrong with your code](http://jsbin.com/seniyarugeqo/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Thanks @KarlenKishmiryan . When I use 
`console.log(results[0].location)`
I get response as
`Object { k: 27.73574, B: 85.33218 }`
Then, I was able to retrieve lat lng using
`results[0].location.k`

I don't know how is this possible but it works.
Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, I was also sure about that @Beterraba but in my case 
`console.log(results[0].location.lat)` returns `function J/<()` in log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using 
`console.log(results[0].location)`

for debugging I get response as

`Object { k: 27.73574, B: 85.33218 }`

then I was able to get lat and lng value using

`results[0].location.k
results[0].location.b`

Don't know how was this possible but it works.